# Turn on GPS in Jellybean

Tags: android, gps

I know this question has been asked a million times. Unfortunately I am still clueless about it. I am also developing an app which tells me to turn on GPS and turn it off. I have tried various suggestions such as these:

1.)

```
private void turnGpsOn (Context context) {
        String beforeEnable = Settings.Secure.getString (context.getContentResolver(),
                                                        Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        String newSet = String.format ("%s,%s",
                                       beforeEnable,
                                       LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        try {
            Settings.Secure.putString (context.getContentResolver(),
                                       Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED,
                                       newSet); 
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
```

2.)

```
                  locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
```

Unfortunately none of these suggestions work . I also had WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS in the AndroidManifest.xml. Still doesnt work. Is there any solution to this problem or is it possible at all to turn on GPS.

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: What exactly do you want? Turn ON the GPS when its OFF?

Answer (score 1):

```
Just Refer my below code
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. But in the Eclipse it says LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED is already deprecated!! I am using Android 4.2.2.